# why does my register cx show a non-zero value?

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I use this segment to move the content from mem1 to mem2. The cx register is supposed to be 0 after the operation. Yet it shows that the content in it is 0B6H. The code is shown below:

```
mem1 DD 3A613H
mem2 DD 25426H
lea si,mem1
lea di,mem2
mov cx,200
cld
rep movsb
hlt
```

The value of cx is 0B6H after the program halts. Can anyone tell me why is that? I don't have any `hlt` instructions among the code segment.

Comment: Please check the tag help for the [tag:assembly] tag - "Please tag the processor and/or the instruction set you are using, as well as the assembler, a valid set should be like this: (assembly, x86, gnu)"

Comment: Why 200 when a DD is 4?

Comment: It would seem that the `rep movsb` finished early, rather than copying the requested 200 bytes, but since 200 bytes is going way off the end of the provided data, we don't know exactly how it will terminate. See the above comment questioning the use of 200 when there isn't nearly that much data.

Comment: Are `mem1` and `2` really contiguous with your code, so a 200-byte copy would copy your code over itself (with an offset)?  If you're single-stepping in a debugger, that would mean `rep movsb` changes to a different instruction after a while.  If you're not single-stepping, I'm not sure what's supposed to happen if `rep movsb` changes its own instruction bytes; its interruptible so it would be unpredictable unless you disabled interrupts.  But probably @ErikEidt is right: probably terminating early on a fault at the end of a segment or something.